Data scraping of multiple pages in R using for loops (rvest package)
I am working on a project that requires scraping some data from a list of webpages (in total, I intend on going through ~1000 pages). Each webpage is formatted very similarly so I can just write a for loop that processes each one identically. The pages use some sort of JavaScript to generate their contents, I think, so this only works with the read_html_live function from the rvest package, as opposed to the more widely used read_html.
I am having some issues with the for loop that I think has to do with the "live" aspect of read_html_live. Basically, if I run the contents of the loop for each individual element of the loop manually, I get the result I want, but when I run the whole loop (i.e., source my R script), it seems to have trouble reading some of the URLs / extracting the elements properly. It doesn't give an error but it just doesn't always provide the expected result, even though I know it's there.
I'm wondering if the read_html_live function is doing some sort of processing in the background that subsequent lines aren't "waiting" an appropriate amount of time for. When I add a Sys.sleep(2) line after the read_html_live operation, everything works as intended, but this is not very exact (and probably makes things slower than they have to be).
I'm wondering if there's a more exact, efficient, or direct way to fix this issue. See my reproducible example below for more context:
require(rvest)
require(tidyverse) # for pipes

# List of sample URLs to iterate over. Each of these pages is formatted very similarly and uses JavaScript to generate certain elements of the page, so read_html_live is needed.
ALL_URLs = c("https://species-registry.canada.ca/index-en.html#/species/19-17",
             "https://species-registry.canada.ca/index-en.html#/species/1096-752",
             "https://species-registry.canada.ca/index-en.html#/species/1097-758",
             "https://species-registry.canada.ca/index-en.html#/species/1349-1011",
             "https://species-registry.canada.ca/index-en.html#/species/502-0",
             "https://species-registry.canada.ca/index-en.html#/species/818-554",
             "https://species-registry.canada.ca/index-en.html#/species/540-61",
             "https://species-registry.canada.ca/index-en.html#/species/1004-679",
             "https://species-registry.canada.ca/index-en.html#/species/963-646",
             "https://species-registry.canada.ca/index-en.html#/species/332-0")

for (url in ALL_URLs) {
  # Read URL
  this_page = read_html_live(url)
  # Sys.sleep(2) # If I comment this out, the output is not as desired, but when included, it works as intended
  # Get relevant HTML element from each page
  this_page %>% html_elements("#cosewic_assessment+ div .sar-definition:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text %>% 
    # Do some formatting of text for it to be more legible and consistent
    str_split_i("\n", 4) %>% trimws %>% 
    # Print out
    message
}

Desired output (which appears with Sys.sleep command):
Acadian Flycatcher
Acadian Redfish, Atlantic population
Acadian Redfish, Bonne Bay population
Acuteleaf Small Limestone Moss
Alaskan Brook Lamprey
Alkaline Wing-nerved Moss
Allegheny Mountain Dusky Salamander
Allegheny Mountain Dusky Salamander, Appalachian population
Allegheny Mountain Dusky Salamander, Carolinian population
American Badger

A typical output without Sys.sleep (it is not always the same suggesting some stochasticity with evaluation times):

Acadian Redfish, Atlantic population
Acadian Redfish, Bonne Bay population
Acuteleaf Small Limestone Moss

Alkaline Wing-nerved Moss






I would encourage you to use Sys.sleep() or other kind of delay function to give the server/page the time to fully respond before consuming the output. Do you experience any errors while processing "delayed" responses? There is even {polite} package https://dmi3kno.github.io/polite/ which emphasizes the policy not to hurry :)

The website “species-registry.canada.ca” retrieves the species information from web API
hosted at “ecprccsarsrch.search.windows.net”. We can directly interact with that API, so we don’t need
read_html_live() or similar.
That API uses an API key and a referer policy to limit direct access to the API. Below, I demonstrate how to
use the httr2 package to create requests that are accepted by the API.
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(httr2)

This function takes an id (the last part of the path of the URLs in your ALL_URLs object) and an
api key. You can retrive an api key by visiting the website in your browser grabbing the API key in
the network tab of the Inspector.
create_perform_request <- function(id, key) {
  request("https://ecprccsarsrch.search.windows.net/indexes/sararegistry-species-indexen-v1/docs/search?api-version=2020-06-30") |>
    req_headers(
      Origin = "https://species-registry.canada.ca",
      Referer = "https://species-registry.canada.ca",
      "api-key" = key
    ) |>
    req_body_json(list(
      filter = paste0("id eq '", id, "'"),
      select = "id,legalStatusId,cosewicStatusId,legalCommonName,cosewicCommonName,cosewicScientificName,legalScientificName,legalPopulation,cosewicPopulation,taxonomyId,emergencyAssessment,cosewicLastAssessmentDate,imageFileName,photoCopyright,legalDateListing,legalScheduleId,underConsiderationId,lastGicDecisionDate,currentGicDecisionId,ranges,cosewicReasonDes,cosewicStatusCriteria,cosewicStatusHis,legalStatusHistory,prevCosewicCommonName,prevCosewicScientificName,ministerReceiptDate,statusChange,azSpecies,hasRelatedSpeciesOnScheduleOne,recProgress,profiles,teams,related"
    )) |>
    req_perform() |>
    resp_body_json()
}

This is the API key I used, it might not work for you. Use your own API key instead.
api_key <- "3A1E8E87503C069448999238ABD05EE9"

We Can perform a single request like this:
resp <-
  create_perform_request("1096-752", api_key)

resp$value[[1]]$cosewicCommonName
#> [1] "Acadian Redfish"

Processing several IDs at once
Extract the IDs from your ALL_URLs object.
ids <- ALL_URLs |>
  map(url_parse) |>
  map(\(x) x$fragment) |>
  map(str_remove, "/.*/")

Run requests for all IDs.
responses <- map(ids, create_perform_request, api_key)
map_chr(responses, \(x) x$value[[1]]$cosewicCommonName)
#>  [1] "Acadian Flycatcher"                  "Acadian Redfish"                    
#>  [3] "Acadian Redfish"                     "Acuteleaf Small Limestone Moss"     
#>  [5] "Alaskan Brook Lamprey"               "Alkaline Wing-nerved Moss"          
#>  [7] "Allegheny Mountain Dusky Salamander" "Allegheny Mountain Dusky Salamander"
#>  [9] "Allegheny Mountain Dusky Salamander" "American Badger"

